# Is there a good Java client for Complete Version 4 Signing Process?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I am working with AWS and need a good Java client that help with the Signing Process for Signature Version 4.  Anyone know of one?  Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, AWS' own SDK provides signing methods already

Comment: Right but we are not using the SDK since we are directly making the HTTPS requests to our endpoints.

Comment: AWS has example code. Before posting a question like this one, Google search. Then post the code that you have written if you have having a problem. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-examples-using-sdks.html#sig-v4-examples-using-sdk-java

Comment: You asked for a "good Java client". AWS' client is a good Java client.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like we may go with [okhttp-aws-signer](https://github.com/babbel/okhttp-aws-signer).  Thanks for your help.